# How to connect to an online database from my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, database, xcode

I want to make a very simple app that connects to a database and retrieves some questions and answers for a quiz.

What is the simplest way to do this? Is Parse the way to go, or is it possible to use a sqlite3 database, which is hosted online? I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to be create a Rest API in any of the server side language like PHP and access your online database. Having said that , this would mean you would require it to be hosted somewhere online. 
The best option in case you don't want to spend on hosting on a server and writing a server side script to access the traditional database would be use to Parse which has options of saving the data in the offline mode in your app and then you can sync it with the database online.
About sqlite3 being hosted online , that won't be a suitable option . I suggest you go for Parse it is easy to learn .

Answer (score 2):

you should NEVER connect your mobile apps directly to a database. you should create a rest api for that, a simple php for example that will be connected to the database and return the results to you.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting data on a server to a mobile app you should use a API Rest, not a direct connection to a database.

You should denitively go for Parse. You would have to implemente nothing on server side and it has an SDK already implemented for iOS that helps you retrieving the information.

Also the free plan could fit you for quite time.

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

Comment: is that a commercial?

Comment: No, I have nothing to do with Parse, but I think it's a useful tool for cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

Best a way for your task - Core Data

If user don't have access of network? How he takes questions and answers?
Just I too building that task.

Parse can use when we want save results test or something data user